# How does Jmeter hit requests to the server

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How does Jmeter perform request to the server: simultaneously or queued? For example, with

```
Thread 5, Ramp-Up =0, Loop Count =1
```

Will in this case all 5 threads hit the server simultaneously, or one hit first while the other four are in a queue?

And I'd also like to know how to do stress and load testing, and what is good ranging and outcome.

Comment: They hit "simultaneously", the second proposition would be e.g : Thread 1 ,Ramp-Up =0, Loop Count =5

Comment: ok , in that case it will be looping for 5 time right?    But In my case the server hit per second graph is varying. and one more thing my throughput is varying (28.4/sec)

Answer (score 0):

If you  send rampup as 0 , all request will start at 1st second after the test is started. The queing system is based on the server config, it has nothing to do with jmeter. As per your config mentioned 5 request will be sent to server in the 1st second itself. If you to to simultanious request for only some or a specified request , add synchronization timer as chiled and set its settings as based on the thread group settings.

For doing load testing you have to analyze your system, server and load balancer if any. Then increase the load gradually and find out how the servers perform in different load. For stress test you have to again increase gradually the load and find in which point the server gets down or start throwing error. And that would be the maximum load the server can handle. If possible get access to the server and analyze the average load , cpu usage and ram of the server. Also make sure  the load balancer is equally distributing the load to each servers.

Comment: But i am getting  different hits per second in graph ranging peak values for every second

Comment: That is why the name , its called as threads. And not requests. Guess of a several person climbing a tree one by one or else in a zero ramp up time. Still the people gets at the tip of each branch in different seconds. By the way if you are putting huge amount of number of threads at 0 rampup it will not go through , it Jmeter will throw error.  So go through some of the basics of jmeter and how analyze how it works with the threads. I think that might solve your issue